# Is there a way to fix a compability issue with beamer?

Tags: beamer, incompatibility

I compile a `beamer` presentation on my Mac, and everything works well, I get what I expect.

However, when I try it on a linux machine, I get the following error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.305 \end{frame}
```

Here is the `frame` around that line (i.e. that ends in line 305):

```
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Probabilistic Grammars}

 \textcolor{blue}{We treat them}

 \begin{equation}
    p
 \end{equation}

 \begin{itemize}
 \item defined over a support 
 \end{itemize}

 \textcolor{mygreen}{Example}
 \end{frame}
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide full minimal examples. I also use Linux with TexLive 2011 and I get no errors if I define `mygreen`.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\listfiles` and `\batchmode` into the preamble of your document, run `pdflatex` or whatever and then compare the file list which can be found at the end of the logfile.

Comment: uh... it seems like \usepackage{enumitem} causes the problem. when I remove the mention of that package and remove all commands that use it, it seems to compile fine. any solutions to that?

Comment: then you have on one computer an old version. Compare the version numbers and install the latest one.

Comment: The `enumitem.sty` currently in TeX Live 2011 is v3.5.1, the version currently provided by Synaptic (for Ubuntu 11.04) is v2.2. If this is the linux distribution you are using and the version difference accounts for your problem then installing TeX Live 2011 on the linux machine would be the best way forward.